# WCF service goes to faulted state while deserializing huge amount of data

Tags: wcf

I have an application which consumes WCF services. My problem is I am fetching around 6000 rows from database, my service shows faulted channel error while deserializing huge amount of data. Infact I have increased the attribute values(like maxStringContentLength,maxArrayLength,maxBytesPerRead,maxNameTableCharCount,CloseTimeOut, SendTimeOut etc..) in service app.config, web.config as well as in the web.config of my web application. But still no luck.

Can anyone please suggest me what to do in this scenario, so that my service wont go to faulted state.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enabling tracing will certainly tell you exactly what the problem is. One possible suspect is the maxItemsInObjectGraph quota (default = 65536) which you can increase by using a `<dataContractSerializer>` element in either a service or an endpoint behavior.

Comment: Hi carlosfigueira, Thanks for your answer, but could you please tell how to do that.